# Are the Internet Explorer Web Controls IE only?

Tags: asp.net, standards, servercontrols

Recently, I came across a set of [Internet Explorer Web Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms529254.aspx) from Microsoft.  These look to me to be older controls from the pre-standards era of Microsoft's asp.net development.  I'm curious as to whether or not these controls work well with modern browsers, or if they're basically IE only.  I know it says it will render to "downlevel" browser, but it seems to indicate that "any browser other than IE" is a downlevel browser.

Are there a modern set of controls from MS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using these - they [aren't supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms528669.aspx) by Microsoft anymore and all the samples are on GotDotNet, which has been shutdown.

You'd have better luck developing with a more recent version of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

THe four control provided (MultiPage, TabStrip, Toolbar, and TreeView) could be done using something like [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#themeGallery).

Comment: There are any number of ways to make things look pretty on the client.  JQuery UI doesn't create server controls.

Comment: However, your answer got me to thinking that you could certainly encapsulate jquery ui in server side controls.  This lead me to find DJ JQuery which does just that.  Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

TreeView doesn't work properly in Chrome.

(the tree displays fine, but expand/collapse actions don't work)